# How to reduce the fetch time of CNContacts?

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

Hi am using `CNContacts` to fetch my contacts but takes around two minutes to display all the contacts in swift.Is there any way to speed up my Fetching time?

```
do
{
    try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(request)
    { contact, stop in
        contacts.append(contact)  
    }
}

catch
{
    print(error)
}

for contact in contacts
{
    let formatter = CNContactFormatter()
    formatter.style = .FullName
    if(((formatter.stringFromContact(contact))) != nil)
    {

        for phoneNumber:CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers
        {
            let number  = (contact.phoneNumbers[0].value as! CNPhoneNumber).valueForKey("digits") as! String
            let lable :String  =  CNLabeledValue.localizedStringForLabel(phoneNumber.label)
            if (lable.containsString("mobile"))
            {
                if((contact.emailAddresses.isEmpty))
                {
                    self.Allemail.addObject((""))
                }
                else
                {
                    self.Allemail.addObject((contact.emailAddresses[0].value))
                }

                self.Contactname=NSString(format:"'%@'",(formatter.stringFromContact(contact))!)
                let contactnumber=NSString(format:"'%@'",number)
                self.ContactsDictionary.addObject(self.Contactname)
                self.allNumbers.addObject(contactnumber as String)

            }

        }

        for i in 0..<self.ContactsDictionary.count
        {

            if(i == 0)
            {
                self.jsonstring = "[{'Name':\(self.ContactsDictionary.objectAtIndex(i)),'Number':\(self.allNumbers.objectAtIndex(i))}"
            }else
            {
                self.jsonstring = "\(self.jsonstring),{'Name':\(self.ContactsDictionary.objectAtIndex(i)),'Number':\(self.allNumbers.objectAtIndex(i))}"
            }


        }
        self.jsonstring = "\(self.jsonstring)]"

    }


}

self.contactupload()
```

Comment: show the code you're using. tell us what instruments tells you takes the longest

Comment: Shared my code @Wain

Comment: You can use `Instruments/Time Profiler` that should help you find what takes time.

Comment: why are you adding all the contacts to a local array? this is a bad idea, you want as few contacts in memory at the same time as you can...

Comment: I have to upload it in a json format as mentioned in the code so i did in this way.Could you please suggest me alternate way of doing it? @ wain